# Docker run mysql-server not initializing

Tags: mysql, docker, exit

I am trying to initialize **mysql** container within **Docker** by the following command:

`docker run --name some-name -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db-name mysql/mysql-server`

It pulls the container successfully, runs everything till it reaches this line and stays there forever:
`2022-02-28T09:10:03.040757Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`

I tried to add this flag `-h 127.0.0.1` still stops at the same line.

This is the output of `docker container ls -a`

`70579fec1ed2 mysql "docker-entrypoint.s…" 3 hours ago Exited (1) 3 hours ago spawning-pool`

This is the last line of the output of `docker logs $(container-name)`

`2022-02-28T10:24:24.316843Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`

Comment: That's normal. Did you expect something else? You might want to add the `-d` option to have the database run detached, so you can use your shell after it starts.

Comment: my purpose was that when I add ```-d``` I would see the process running in the background when I use ```docker ps```. when I add ```-d``` and call ```docker ps``` nothing shows there and only it shows in ```docker ps -a``` that ***mysql*** did exit while I never command it too.

Comment: Please paste output of `docker container ls -a`

Comment: Also, post the output of `docker logs some-name` (replacing 'some-name' with the actual name of your mysql container)

Comment: I edited with the output of ```docker container ls -a```
The output of ```docker logs some-name``` is quite but added it's ending

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be adding the flag:

`-it`  and adding at the end `/bin/bash`

So finally the ending of the command looks like this:

`-it -d mysql:mysql-server /bin/bash`

Which will run a terminal in the background of mysql and keep it from closing.
Only I hope someone to correct me if this will cause any future errors that a ***bash terminal*** is constantly running.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. The mysql container should run (it shouldn't shutdown) until it is pulled down, i.e. if I run `docker run --name mysql-demo -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword -d mysql:latest` I can then do `docker exec -it mysql-demo bash` and everything works

Comment: when I ran it without /bin/bash it still went off after few seconds

Comment: I receive this error:
```Error response from daemon: Container 62ca44a48324105253dda554b47a8f89a2484ef45ebb85ff777773b60e58331d is not running```